# Code design for a 2D game

Tags: oop, game-engine, ooad

I am in need of some resources on how to design the main components of a basic 2d game.
Let's call it an "engine". How should I design my renderer, scene manager, entity manager a.s.o. and how should they interact with each other? What about event management, resource management, ...

Maybe someone has some cool UML? Or any "tutorial"? Some general hints and tips?

Comment: Perhaps you should check out http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Jason-Gregory/dp/1568814135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually also struggled some in order to get a hold of some good tutorial for a while. I found tons of mediocre sites with working game-code but lacking explanations.

What helped me the most was probably just skimming through game code I found casually looking around, and also reading the chapters of the book on this site: [Killer Game Programming with Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/)

You can find some game-code to look through on these sites:

http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html

http://www.javacooperation.gmxhome.de/TutorialStartEng.html

Hope you found this helpful!